# ¿El tab de sin responder está mal?

Tags: soporte, barra-superior

Cuando intentas filtrar por preguntas sin responder, esta las ordena y pone las que están sin responder al final, y además muestra las que tienen respuesta al principio.

Comment: sin responder es: sin respuesta aceptada.

Comment: ya vi como dices ahora la cierro gracias

Answer (score 6):

Las preguntas "sin reponder" esta filtrada por:

- Preguntas que tengan respuestas pero que estas no hayan sido aceptadas, o
- Preguntas que tengan respuestas con un puntaje no mayor que 0

Comment: Quedaria mejor el segundo punto como "Preguntas que no tengan respuestas con un puntaje mayor que 0"? (Incluyendo las que no tienen ninguna respuesta)