# Error en la consulta de preguntas sin responder

Tags: soporte, búsqueda, preguntas-no-contestadas

Navegando en la versión para móviles, entre a la parte de **preguntas sin responder**

Como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Preguntas sin responder]

Luego al ver el paginador que son **342 páginas** es extraño y al ir la última página me doy cuenta que están las preguntas sin responder y están las preguntas que ya fueron respondidas.

Como se muestra en esta imagen se puede ver preguntas con **respuestas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede ser lo mismo que [esta otra publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/102/250). Las preguntas se consideran sin responder si ninguna de sus respuestas tiene votos positivos.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Puede ser solo que no dice si es la versión para móviles o es la web, por lo que he visto son diferentes

Comment: Es exactamente lo que te respondió @Alvaro. **Sin responder** significa preguntas no cerradas, sin respuestas votadas positivamente, ni respuestas aceptadas. Para filtrar las que no tienen ninguna respuesta, hay que ir a **[No hay respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)** (323 páginas).

Comment: @Mariano Entonces que hago borro esta pregunta

Comment: @RaulCacacho yo la dejaría, cerrándola como duplicada... No entendí en resto. ¿Editar qué?

Comment: @Mariano lo que me confunde que en la web cuando entro a la ultima pagina del paginador me aparecen todas las pregunta y ninguna tiene respuesta

Comment: No entiendo. En esa última página, te muestra preguntas que **sí** tienen respuestas, pero que están **sin responder** porque ninguna tuvo un voto positivo. Por ejemplo, la primera que aparece en tu captura es https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/34630/127. Fijate que tiene 6 respuestas, pero todas con 0 votos... Eso para el sistema es "Sin responder"... Probablemente haya alguna que merezca un voto entre esas 6, votá una respuesta y vas a ver cómo desaparece del filtro "Sin responder".

Comment: Quizás te sirva verlo expresado como fórmula y la consulta en SEDE: [¿Cómo funciona la estadística “porcentaje de preguntas contestadas” en Area 51?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/985/127)

Comment: Gracias @Mariano me quedo más claro